# Verifying that the extreme value copula is indeed a copula

Tags: distribution, copula

Given the extreme value copula as defined in [Schölzel/Friederichs (2008)](http://www2.meteo.uni-bonn.de/staff/CSchoelzel/sources/SchoelzelEtal2008Copulas.pdf),
how does one verify that $\frac{\partial C(u_1, u_2)}{\partial u_1} \geq 0?$ For the LHS, I have $$\exp\left[\log(u_1u_2)A\left(\frac{\log(u_2)}{\log(u_1u_2)}\right)\right]\left[\frac{1}{u_1}A\left(\frac{\log(u_2)}{\log(u_1u_2)}\right)-\frac{\log(u_2)}{u_1\log(u_1u_2)}A^{\prime}\left(\frac{\log(u_2)}{\log(u_1u_2)}\right)\right]$$

The derivative is causing difficulty. Any help on progressing would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, you only need to show that
\begin{align*}
A\left(\frac{\log(u_2)}{\log(u_1u_2)}\right)-\frac{\log(u_2)}{\log(u_1u_2)}A'\left(\frac{\log(u_2)}{\log(u_1u_2)}\right) \ge 0,
\end{align*}
or, for any $t \in (0, 1)$,
\begin{align*}
A(t) - t A'(t) \ge 0.
\end{align*}
Recall that $A$ is a convex function from $[0,\, 1]$ to $[1/2,\, 1]$, $A(0)=A(1)=1$, and $A(t) \ge \max(t, 1-t)$. From the convexity, the path from the function is always above the tangent line at any point. That is, for any $\xi, t \in (0, 1)$, 
\begin{align*}
A(\xi) \ge A(t) + A'(t) (\xi -t).
\end{align*} 
Let $\xi\rightarrow 1$, 
\begin{align*}
1 \ge A(t) + A'(t) (1 -t).
\end{align*} 
In other words,
\begin{align*}
A'(t) (1 -t) &\le 1-A(t)\\
&\le 1-t.
\end{align*}
Consequently, $A'(t) \le 1$. Then,
\begin{align*}
A(t) - t A'(t) \ge A(t) - t \ge 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: I don’t know why this hasn’t been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Attached contains a very detailed account (also see appendix A for derivation ofnyhe derivative):

https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/1145695/1145695.pdf

Hope this helps.